# Participle clauses in between the main clause?

Tags: grammar, present-participles

1. can we use a participle clause in between the main clause?
   for example: 
   *The restaurant will open next week and employ 10 people.*

*The restaurant, opening next week, will employ 10 people.* -- used in the middle
*Opening next week, the restaurant will employ 10 people.*-- initial position

2. can I use them interchangeably ?
3. if [1] is possible, can we use them without using *commas*?

--> *Police investigating the crime are looking for three men.* (police are investigating the crime)
I read this example in the book *English Grammar in Use* on page no. 194, its explanation says *'We use -ing clauses to say what somebody (or something) is (or was) doing at a particular time.*

This explanation for using a participle clause directly after the subject in the main clause seems to have the same meaning as using a participle clause to give more information about the main clause's subject because both explanations talk about additional information about the subject.


my opinion: I think [1] and [3] are possible.

Comment: 1 Yes, 2 Yes, and 3 "police investigating the scene" distinguishes those police from other police; "investigating the scene" is integral not supplementary.

Comment: @TimR there is another example that shows that ‘the police investigating the crime’ and ‘the police looking for three men’ are the same police. another example from the same section:- ‘who is the women taking to tom?’ -ing clause talks about the women.

Comment: Sorry if I didnt make myself clear. I wasn't referring to distinguishing these police from other police who may have been mentioned in the news article. The clause is a defining clause, not supplementary information about **police** in the sentence.

Comment: Whereas *opening next week* in "The restaurant, opening next week, will employ ten people."  is supplemental. It doesn't play a defining or specifying role.

Comment: If you don't put a comma between "police" and "investigating the crime" then it's taken as  distinguishing which police you're referring to. Adding the comma makes it supplemental.

Comment: No comma = "The police who are investigating the crime...". Comma = "The police while investigating the crime ..."

Comment: @Barmar I got it. thanks!